# Is there any way to lock multiple expanded items on TreeView?

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, winrt-xaml-toolkit

I would like to force the `TreeView` control to expand only **one item of the same level** at once.

The picture shows how a father, son and grand-son are spread:

[image: Screenshot]

If the user would tap on the item with header *Men's Singles Semi-Finals*, the currently expanded item (*Men's Singles*) should appear collapsed.

I would like to avoid collapsing the items manually so I was wondering if there was any implementation of that behavior :)

Thanks again!

Comment: Then what you want to do with the left items of the same level? I'm a little confused, can you please show a picture?

Comment: edited the question with further information